# Site master page settings page does not list all the master pages

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a sub site under a parent site and when I created a master page in this sub site, It is showing up in the list in "_catalog/Master pages". But when I try to change master page for this sub site in "_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx", It only shows some of the master pages from parent site only. The master page file is checked in. 
Out of 3 master page files in drop down list, "Customv4.master" is not published and is Draft. The other two are Published and has been Approved.
So it is not about Publishing, or approval?

Is there anything else I have to do for these master pages to be be shown in the Drop down list in "_Layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [SharePoint](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) community

Comment: How did you deployed your master page to the sharepoint site collection ? Did you deployed it using a Site level featuere? If yes, then can you please try to deactivate and reactivate your feature? let me know the outcome for this Thanks

Comment: Hi,
I created a master page and checked in, publish and approved it. And now it is listed in drop down. Although, some of the pages which have been created by someone else earlier has status as approved and are not listed in dop down. However my problem is solved.